# Issue using JXL.jar

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jxl

Issue - Getting following error when using JXL.jar to write to the excel file:-

```
jxl.common.AssertionFailed
at jxl.common.Assert.verify(Assert.java:37)
at jxl.write.biff.CompoundFile.readAdditionalPropertySets(CompoundFile.java:398)
at jxl.write.biff.CompoundFile.<init>(CompoundFile.java:209)
at jxl.write.biff.File.close(File.java:116)
at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.close(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:456)
```

Read forums and looks like it has something to do with the version of the JXL.jar file. Hence, downloaded the latest version. Also, the excel file is closed while running the code. So, that issue is ruled out.

Comment: What version of Excel was the spreadsheet formatted as?  Sometimes I use POI and it supports the .xls and the .xlsx formats.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue. The excel file that the code was writing to had 'Read-only' property set. Once that was removed, the code was able to write to the excel file just fine.